# want to rewrite an URL in wordpress

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

i want rewrite some urls in wordpress

```
from http://localhost/wordpress/my-page/2/

to http://localhost/wordpress/my-page/part-2/
```

anyone can help?
Now i am using something like this but it not working.

```
    function rewrite_url()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(my-page)/([^/]*)/?', 
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&my-page=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_url');
```